# Step by Step instructions on installing Bitcoin Core 0.14 on Raspberry Pi Zero and 1/2/3?

Tags: bitcoin-core, raspberry-pi, installation

I couldn't find a concise tutorial on how to setup Bitcoin Core v0.14 on Raspberry Pi Zero or 1/2/3. Let's say I have a brand new raspberry pi without any image flashed. What are the step by step instructions to get this thing running as a Bitcoin Core node? Assume I only have a 4GB SD card as I noticed that the new .14 version of Core has the ability to prune the blockchain all the way down to 500mb.

Comment: There are ARM binaries out there (e.g., the Bitcoin Core fork [Bitcoin Knots](https://bitcoinknots.org/) provides ARM binaries).

Comment: You have to show us what you tried.

Comment: It is primarily v0.13 (Oct 2016), but it does mention the 14 branch --  http://raspnode.com/diy.html Maybe at least a starting point for the 14 steps?

Comment: Pruning has been supported since 0.11, nothing new.

Comment: If I could find my Raspberry Pi  I would gladly write you a step-by-step guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a guide I used to install a full node on a Raspberry Pi 3B with 1GB of RAM.

You have to compile the code and therefore need a RAM swap on an external HDD. Make sure it is mounted correctly, or it will wear out the sd card!

https://medium.com/@meeDamian/bitcoin-full-node-on-rbp3-revised-88bb7c8ef1d1

Answer (score 0):

raspnode.com is definitely the place to do a Bitcoin node on a Raspberry Pi. It's a long haul getting the entire blockchain, but if you only had a small blockchain after much pruning I suppose it could be done. I tried running bitcoin-qt on a RPi 1, and it just stunk. I then tried it on a RPi 3, and it still was a struggle. But I was going for the full blockchain, and still am. If you have a tiny pruned blockchain, you might be able to get away with using a Pi Zero. What I have done to ease the pain of getting blocks indexed and everything else, I installed bitcoin-qt on my desktop computer under Ubuntu. I used an NFS share on my NAS to access the bitcoin folder from both machines, and was able to do all of the heavy lifting on my much faster desktop computer. Once I had the whole blockchain, I switched back to the RPi 3 and everything was good. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about setting it up on a RP0 because I've only set mine up on RP3 but this is a really great full node tutorial:

[Damian Mee's RP3 Full Node Tutorial](https://medium.com/@meeDamian/bitcoin-full-node-on-rbp3-revised-88bb7c8ef1d1)

I used this one for setting up a lightning full node on RP3 and if you like this one better you can use it for the regular full node just stop before the lightning part.

[Brett Morrison's LN Node on RP3](https://brettmorrison.com/running-a-bitcoin-lightning-full-node-on-raspberry-pi)